# Incrementing sub-sets of matrices in Python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I want to increment a small subsection (variable) of an matrix [illustrative code below] - but running over them by loops seems sloppy and inelegant -- and I suspect is the slowest way to do this calc. 
One of the ideas I had was to create another array of ones, of the dimensions that i want to increment (2x3 in example below) and to pad this temporary array with zeros so it was of the same dimensions as the original. I could then sum them.

Not sure how to accomplish this padding in `numpy` - or if that is the most performant way of doing this calculation? I'd like to try and optimize this as much as possible.

```
>>> import numpy as np    
>>> a = np.zeros((10,10))
>>> for i in range(3,5):
...     for x in range(4,7):
...         a[i][x] += 1
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the same simply by:

```
 a[3:5,4:7] += 1
```

Comment: so this seems to take a long time on relatively large matrices (2000 x 2000) typically - any way I can optimize this?

Comment: @flyingcrab. Unfortunately I don't know. Maybe it is possible to use numpy on GPU.

Comment: @flyingcrab: `timeit M[3:5,4:7] += 1` reports that it takes `6.6` microseconds regardless of the matrix size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also logical arrays for accessing individual elements of your subset. Especially handy when your subset has irregular shape.

Also they perform very well. For example

```
In []: M= randn(2000, 2000)
In []: timeit M[M< 0]+= 10
1 loops, best of 3: 42.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: It appears the speed is pretty contingent on available ram - i suppose thats the bottleneck, atm timeit for me ~ 1s!

Comment: @flyingcrab there is not much to optimize if you are running out of physical memory. However 2000x2000 array is not really very big, if `M.dtype== dtype('float64')` then `M.nbytes== 32000000`. You can retime with smaller matrix, for example with 1000x1000 my timings is around `10 ms`. So you could roughly estimate that performance depends linearly on the number of elements.